# How to standard-print `dir()` and other calls in Ipython

Tags: python, ipython

So generally `Ipython` prints result in single column lists:

```
In [155]: dir()
Out[155]: 
['In',
 'Out',
 '_',
 '_100',
 '_101',
 '_102',
```

etc. How do I print this in the normal interactive-shell format?

```
>>> dir()
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__']
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [IPython interactive shell output formatting configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232333/ipython-interactive-shell-output-formatting-configuration)

Comment: `%pprint` toggles it on and off.

Comment: Also, `%who` or `%whos` will show you variables in your namespace excluding all the ones that IPython defines for you (like `In`, `Out`, `_`, `_100`...)

Comment: Filed an issue to make pretty printing smarter for cases like this: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/7821

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just `print` it:

```
In [1]: print(dir())
['In', 'Out', '_', '__', '___', '__builtin__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '_dh', '_i', '_i1', '_ih', '_ii', '_iii', '_oh', '_sh', 'exit', 'get_ipython', 'quit']
```